# how to bind click event in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make custom directive in angularjs .I am able to make custom directive of menu option 
actually the menu option is this https://jqueryui.com/menu/
 .But I need the menu option will display only when user **click** or **mouseover** event on button.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVNqMg

```
var app = angular.module("ionicApp", ['ionic']);
app.directive('custommenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            $(element).menu();
        }
    }
});
app.controller('cnt', function($scope) {
    $scope.showMenu = function() {
        // Code here
    }
});
```

how to bind click or mouse over event with custom directive ?

Comment: Click event in directive `element.bind('click', function(){
                 //code here 
                });`

Answer (score 3):

Use ngClick and ngMouseOver directives respectively

- [ngMouseover](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover)
- [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

e.g.

```
<div ng-controller="cnt">
    <button ng-click="showMenu()">Click for menu</button>
    <button ng-mouseover="showMenu()">Hover for menu</button>
</div>
```

edit:

need to call menu() on the element. Should be able to pass element through like below, though this might need editing as I haven't tested the code.

```
$scope.showMenu = function(element) {
    element.menu();
}

<div ng-controller="cnt">
    <button ng-click="showMenu($element)">Click for menu</button>
    <button ng-mouseover="showMenu($element)">Hover for menu</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I need to show menu on button click ..currently  it is display on load

Comment: Should be able to pass $element in like showMenu($element)? I'll update the answer, but it might need adjusting as i haven't had a chance to test it.

Comment: @sham first try to understand my problem .Currently my menu option is display when i run the application.I need it only show when user click on button

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the controller to the directive to use its api

```
var app=angular.module("ionicApp",['ionic']);
app.directive('custommenu',function(){    
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{

        },
        controller: 'cnt',
        link:function(scope,element,attr,ctrl){

            $(element).menu();
            $(element).find('li').click(function(){
              scope.showMenu()

            })
        }
    }
})
app.controller('cnt',function($scope){
 $scope.showMenu=function(){
   alert('im here');
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var app=angular.module("ionicApp",['']);
  app.directive('custommenu',function(){    
    return{
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{

        },
        link:function(scope,element,attr){

           element.bind('click', function() {

                       // Write your code here
           });
       }
    }
});

app.controller('cnt', function($scope) {

       $scope.isMenuVisible=false;
       $scope.showMenu = function() {

             $scope.isMenuVisible=true;
       }
  });
```

Avoid using jquery to bind events within angular js

// Update to show menu on click event of some button

```
<div ng-controller="cnt">
<button ng-click="showMenu()">Show menu</button>
```

Now use the scope variable : isMenuVisible to cotrol visibility of menu as:

```
<div class="menu" data-ng-if="isMenuVisible">    
</div>
```

I added a JsFiddle version of the answer at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qkff1g7x/)

Comment: Actually I need to show menu on button click ..which is now display on load

Comment: Do you load the html for menu initially?

Comment: first try to understand my problem .Currently my menu option is display when i run the application.I need it only show when user click on button